# How to completely hide Link React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have created sidebar with settings where user can hide or show sections he needs.

Here is how this components looks like:

```js
<List>
 {section.elements.map((subsection) => (
   <ListItem key={subsection.name}>
     {settings ? (
       <Checkbox
         checked={subsection.show}
         onChange={() => {
           subsection.show = !subsection.show
           setSidebar((prev) => [...prev])
         }}
       />
     ) : null}
     {subsection.show || settings ? (
       <Link href={section.routePrefix + subsection.href} passHref>
         <Button
           sx={{
             color:
               router.pathname.includes(`${section.routePrefix + subsection.href}`)
                 ? 'secondary.main'
                 : 'primary.main',
             width: "100%",
             justifyContent: "start"
           }}
           startIcon={subsection.icon}
         >
           {subsection.name}
         </Button>
     </Link>
     ) : null}
   </ListItem>
 ))}
</List>
```

I have problem with peace of code that starts with `subsection.show || settings`. As you can see, if this condition is false, I just show nothing to user, but in fact, on front end it doesn't work. After compile, it still looks like there is `li` tag.

This is how it looks like on front end.

[image]

So, my question is, how to completely hide this component, maybe not even compile. I was trying to set display none and hidden on different ways, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are supposed to do:

```
<List>
      {section.elements.map((subsection) =>
        subsection.show || settings ? (
          <ListItem key={subsection.name}>
            {settings ? (
              <Checkbox
                checked={subsection.show}
                onChange={() => {
                  subsection.show = !subsection.show;
                  setSidebar((prev) => [...prev]);
                }}
              />
            ) : null}
            <Link href={section.routePrefix + subsection.href} passHref>
              <Button
                sx={{
                  color: router.pathname.includes(
                    `${section.routePrefix + subsection.href}`
                  )
                    ? "secondary.main"
                    : "primary.main",
                  width: "100%",
                  justifyContent: "start"
                }}
                startIcon={subsection.icon}
              >
                {subsection.name}
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </ListItem>
        ) : null
      )}
    </List>
```